# Как возобновить стандартный torrc файл?

Tags: tor

Как возобновить стандартный torrc файл ? Как вернуть стандартные настройки torrc файла ? Попробовал sudo systemctl restart tor, но в папке /etc/tor файл torrc не появился ?

Comment: Вот нашёл на [github.gist](https://gist.github.com/dhurley14/8d4b8d8ac98d74b1e665). А так, увы, не знаю.

Comment: Не уверен насчет _tor_ но `systemctl restart` обычно никогда не перезаписывает файлы конфигурации. Попробуйте переустановить

Answer (score 0):

просто закомментируйте (ну или вообще удалите) все строки в этом файле. тогда программа будет использовать умолчальные значения всех параметров.

комментарий, как и в подавляющем большинстве конфигурационных файлов — это символ `#` в начале строки.